# Add a UIImageView to a Tableview

Tags: iphone, uitableview, uiimageview

I have an asychronous image loader which loads images (JImage) in a UIImageview. I want to display these in a tablecell. Obviously i cant set cell.imageView.image because i dont have an image, i just have a view.

How do i set the UIImageview to the tablecell? cell.backgroundView works though, but that paints over the whole cell.

The JImage code is:

```
    NSURL *theUrl=[NSURL URLWithString:imageURL];
JImage *photoImage=[[JImage alloc] init];
[photoImage initWithImageAtURL:theUrl];
[photoImage setContentMode:UIViewContentModeRedraw];
[photoImage setFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 40.0f, 65.0f)];
cell.backgroundView = photoImage;
[photoImage release];
```

which in the JImage.m:

```
- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection*)theConnection 
{
     [self setImage:[UIImage imageWithData: data]]; 
}
```

Comment: You could always just grab the `UIImage` from your `UIImageView`, and then pass that to the cell's `UIImageView`.  Like `cell.imageView.image = myImageView.image`.

Comment: You're reinventing the wheel. The Three20 library already has a good, solid async loaded image class, and it can be dropped straight into a tableview

Comment: That looks really cool. If i knew there had been a wheel like that, I would've have made such a squareish wheel. thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this code and set frame according to your need.

```
UIImage *imagearrow = [UIImage imageNamed:@"arrow.png"];    
UIImageView *imgarrow=[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(290, 25, 7, 15)];
imgarrow.image =imagearrow;
[cell addSubview:imgarrow];
[imagearrow release];
```

Comment: Aww that was it, [cell addSubView:imageview]; I completely forgot addSubview. thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use JImage if all you want to do is load the image asynchronously. One easy way to do this is with GCD and blocks, like so: https://github.com/ChrisTec/iPhone-Book-CodeSamples/blob/master/Chapter%2013/RealEstateViewer%2013.2.5/RealEstateViewer/ImageTableViewController.m

Here's a sample chapter of the book Objective-C Fundamentals which I've co-authored that explains this code in depth: http://www.manning.com/fairbairn/OCF_sample_ch13.pdf

To sum it up: When the cell is requested, you look if you already have downloaded the image. If you have, you display it. If not, you display a spinner and start an async GCD block that will fetch the image. One that block is done, it will run another block on the main thread that switches the spinner out for the image. That's all.

Comment: When i have some spare time, i'll look at your method. It seems very solid, but not at all a simple 5 minute fix. Thanks though! :)

Comment: That might be true, but simple 5 minute fixes often bite you in the butt later.

Comment: But it saves my butt from getting shot by my boss instead of bitten right now.

Comment: Fair enough :) But then it will be both bitten and shot some time down the road :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you should take a different approach to this. Instead of putting your JImage in the cell, hold it somewhere else in the view controller, an `NSArray` is usually convenient. Then populate the cells with either placeholder images or just leave them empty.

So let's say you have an array with all the JImages that are loading, when the JImage in the position x of the array finishes loading, you reload that specific cell as it follows:

```
NSIndexPath indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:x inSection:0];
[self.tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:x withRowAnimation:NO];
```

And in your `cellForRow:AtIndexPath` you just have to take the image from the JImage object held in the array.

I hope this helps you